# Hide button for tablet using angular device detector service

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to hide a element on tablet only using angular ngx device detector service.

I've done this using css media queries.However, I wanna see if I can get the same result using ngx device detector.

Html

```
<div id="hide-download">
          <app-button name="download" classAttr="btn-primary" (click)="downloadFile()" [disabled]="!allOrders || allOrders.length === 0">
              <i class="fas fa-download button-icon-padding"></i>
              Download
          </app-button>
```

Angular service ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ExampleDeviceDetectorService {

  public deviceInfo: any;
  public isMobile: any;
  public isTablet: any;
  public isDesktop: any;

  constructor(
    public deviceService: DeviceDetectorService
  ) {
    this.getDeviceInfo();
  }

  getDeviceInfo() {
    this.deviceInfo = this.deviceService.getDeviceInfo();
    this.isMobile = this.deviceService.isMobile();
    this.isTablet = this.deviceService.isTablet();
    this.isDesktop = this.deviceService.isDesktop();
  }

}
```

I expected for the button to not be shown on tablet devices.

Comment: you can call the service from your component and use *ngIf="!isTablet" to remove the element from DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the service into your component

sample.component.ts

```
constructor(private exampleDeviceDetectorService: ExampleDeviceDetectorService) {}
```

Use *ngIf to remove the element from DOM

sample.component.html

```
<div id="hide-download" *ngIf="!exampleDeviceDetectorService.isTablet">
    <app-button name="download" classAttr="btn-primary" 
    (click)="downloadFile()" [disabled]="!allOrders || allOrders.length === 0">
        <i class="fas fa-download button-icon-padding"></i>
            Download
    </app-button>
</div>
```

Use [hidden] to hide the element from DOM

sample.component.html

```
<div id="hide-download" [hidden]="!exampleDeviceDetectorService.isTablet">
    <app-button name="download" classAttr="btn-primary" 
    (click)="downloadFile()" [disabled]="!allOrders || allOrders.length === 0">
        <i class="fas fa-download button-icon-padding"></i>
            Download
    </app-button>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add your component code? and is there any other error you are getting